# Extract JSON from String using flutter dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Hello I want to extract JSON from below input string.

I have tried bellow regex in java and it is working fine,

```
private static final Pattern shortcode_media = Pattern.compile("\"shortcode_media\":(\\{.+\\})");
```

I want in regex for dart.

**Input String**

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.__initialDataLoaded(window._sharedData);</script><script type="text/javascript">window.__additionalDataLoaded('/p/B9fphP5gBeG/',{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphSidecar","id":"2260708142683789190","shortcode":"B9fphP5gBeG","dimensions":{"height":1326,"width":1080}}}});</script><script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">window.__initialDataLoaded(window._newData);</script><script type="text/javascript">window._newData('/p/B9fphP5gBeG/',{"graphql":{"post":{"__typename":"id","id":"2260708142683789190","new_code":"B9fphP5gBeG"}}});</script><script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
  function normalizeError(err) {
    var errorInfo = err.error || {};
    var getConfigProp = function(propName, defaultValueIfNotTruthy) {
      var propValue = window._sharedData && window._sharedData[propName];
      return propValue ? propValue : defaultValueIfNotTruthy;
    };
    return {}
  }
)
```

**Expected json**

```
{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphSidecar","id":"2260708142683789190","shortcode":"B9fphP5gBeG","dimensions":{"height":1326,"width":1080}}}}
```

**Note:** There are multiple json string in input string, i need json of **shortcode_media** tag

Comment: [RegExp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
void main() {
​
  String json = '''
  {"graphql":
{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphSidecar","id":"2260708142683789190","shortcode":"B9fphP5gBeG","dimensions":{"height":1326,"width":1080}}},
"abc":{"def":"test"}    
}
  ''';

  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
  "\"shortcode_media\":(\\{.+\\})",
  caseSensitive: false,
  multiLine: false,
);

  print(regExp.stringMatch(json).toString());


}
```

output

```
"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphSidecar","id":"2260708142683789190","shortcode":"B9fphP5gBeG","dimensions":{"height":1326,"width":1080}}}
```

Dartpad

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding Dart RegExp would be:

```dart
static final RegExp shortcodeMedia = RegExp(r'"shortcode_media":(\{.+\})");
```

It does not work, though. JSON is not a regular language, so you can't parse it using regular expressions.

The value of `"shortcode_media"` in your example JSON ends with several `}` characters. The RegExp will stop the match at the *third* of those, even though the second `}` is the one matching the leading `{`. If your JSON text contains any further values after the `shortcode_media` entry, those might be included as well.

Stopping at the first `}` would also be too short.
If someone reorders the JSON source code to the equivalent

```
"shortcode_media":{"dimensions":{"height":1326,"width":1080},"__typename":"GraphSidecar","id":"2260708142683789190","shortcode":"B9fphP5gBeG"}
```

(that is, putting the `"dimensions"` entry first), then you would only capture until the end of the dimensions block.

I would recommend either using a proper JSON parser, or at least improving the RegExp to be able to handle a single nested JSON object - since you seem to already know that it will happen.
Such a RegExp could be:

```dart
RegExp(r'"shortcode_media":(\{(?:[^{}]*(?:\{.*?\})?)*?\})')
```

This RegExp will capture the correct number of braces for the example code, but still won't work if there are more nested JSON objects. Only a real parser can handle the general case correctly.